# ArduinoJson buffer corruption

Tags: esp32

I have a very wierd behavior using two different ArduinoJson (6.17.3) objects on my ESP32. I was not able to reproduce it in a small example but could track it down to some extent.

From MQTT I receive a json string `payload` (actually it is a const char*) looking like this:

```
{"getLog": {"BOOL": false}, "restartESP": {"BOOL": false}, "config": {"M": {"cRI": {"N": "1200000"}, "cST": {"N": "120000"}, "SSID": {"S": "smartabell"}, "cAL": {"BOOL": true}, "PW": {"S": "smartabell"}}}, "OTA": {"S": "99"}, "time": {"S": ""}, "updateConfig": {"BOOL": false}, "MAC": {"S": "84:CC:A8:00:E7:94"}}
```

I store it in

```
DynamicJsonDocument mqttJsonDoc(MY_MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
deserializeJson(mqttJsonDoc, payload);
```

for further parsing, which works fine at the beginning. However, when I call the following function to ACK the MQTT package (it is called in the same function where `mqttJsonDoc` is created):

```
bool ackDDBAction(const char *new_val, const char *ack_pub_topic)
{
    /* JSON settings */
    DynamicJsonDocument ackJsonDoc(MQTT_MAX_ACK_SIZE);
    ackJsonDoc["MAC"] = MAC_str;
    ackJsonDoc["ACK"] = "";
    ackJsonDoc["updateConfig"] = new_val;
    /* Calculate buffer length */
    size_t jsonSize = measureJson(ackJsonDoc) + 1;
    char jsonBuffer[jsonSize];
    /* Serialize json object into a char array */
    serializeJson(ackJsonDoc, jsonBuffer, jsonSize);
    /* Send ack */
    ack_success = client.publish(ack_pub_topic, jsonBuffer);

    return ack_success;
}
```

Somehow my original json object `mqttJsonDoc` is corrupted and looks like:

```
{"getLog":{"BOOL":false},"restartESP":{"BOOL":false},"config":{"M":{"cRI":{"N":"1200000"},"cST":{"N":"120000"},"SSID":{"S":"smartabell"},"cAL":{"BOOL":true},"PW":{"S":"smartabell"}}},"OTA":{"S":"99"},"time":{"S":""},"updateConfig":{"BOOL":false},"MAC":{"S":"84:CC:A8:00:E7:94"}}{"ub{\"MAC\":\"84CCA800E794\",\"ACK\":\"\",\"getLog\":\"0\"}0000":{"\":\"84CCA800E794\",\"ACK\":\"\",\"getLog\":\"0\"}0000":false},"CCA800E794\",\"ACK\":\"\",\"getLog\":\"0\"}0000":{",\"ACK\":\"\",\"getLog\":\"0\"}0000":false},"\":\"\",\"getLog\":\"0\"}0000":{"etLog\":\"0\"}0000":{"Log\":\"0\"}0000":{":\"0\"}0000":"0\"}0000"},"cST":{"N":"120000"},"SSID":{"S":"smartabell"},"cAL":{"BOOL":true},"PW":{"S":"smartabell"}}},"OTA":{"S":"99"},"time":{"S":""},"updateConfig":{"BOOL":false},"MAC":{"S":"84:CC:A8:00:E7:94"}}
```

The beginning is similar, but in the middle, fragments of the other jsonDocument `ackJsonDoc` appear. Besides, it is full of escape chars `\`. After some debugging, I found out that **only** when the line `serializeJson(ackJsonDoc, jsonBuffer, jsonSize);` is executed `mqttJsonDoc` gets corrupted.

I played around with dynamic and static json document but it didnt change the behavior, besides out of curiosity, I created another json object to see if somehow there was a memory overlap.

```
    DynamicJsonDocument mqttJsonDoc2(MY_MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
    deserializeJson(mqttJsonDoc2, payload);
```

But this additional dynamic json document holding the payload as well, is corrupted when `ackDDBAction()` is called, too. Increasing any of the json objects by size did not lead to an improvement as well.

I was looking for known issues and cavities but didnt find anything in the documentation https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejson/.

But maybe someone has an idea or faced this issue before - I could do some work arounds but they would be ugly and I would like to understand what is happening here.